# How to retry when the API calls fails after subscribing in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor, angular-httpclient, retrywhen

I am calling an API to get random details. The problem is that, sometimes I am getting 502 error as bad gateway and it may also break due to a bad network connection also.
Below is my code to API call

```
// COMPONENT API CALL SUBSCRIBE
     this._service.post('randomAPI/getdetails', filters).subscribe((response: any) => {
     this.itemList = response;    
   });

// SHARED SERVICE
     post<T>(url: string, body: any): Observable<T> {
     return this.httpClient.post<T>(url, body);
   }
```

Whenever I get 500 or 502 server error, using an Interceptor I am routing to a error page to notify the user as server issue.

Instead, can I make the API to try one more time in component level or interceptor level if it fails and then route to error page?

```
// INTERCEPTOR
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 400 || error.status === 403) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('abort-access', { replaceUrl: true });
        } else if (error.status === 500 || error.status === 502) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('server-error', { replaceUrl: true });
        }
        return throwError("error occured");
     }));
    }
```

I saw few examples as they are using pipe and adding retryWhen() to achieve this. But as I am very new to angular, I am not able to figure out a way to do it.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to retry?

Comment: Only when it fails, to be precise mostly on 500 and 502 error status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `retryWhen` operator. The principle behind this is that you throw an error when you *don't* want to retry.

`retryWhen` is effectively a fancy `catchError` that will automatically retry unless an error is thrown.

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    // retryWhen operator should come before catchError operator as it is more specific
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      // inside the retryWhen, use a tap operator to throw an error 
      // if you don't want to retry
      tap(error => {
        if (error.status !== 500 && error.status !== 502) {
          throw error;
        }
      })
    )),

    // now catch all other errors
    catchError(error => {     
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 400 || error.status === 403) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('abort-access', { replaceUrl: true });
      }

      return throwError("error occured");
    })
  );
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyxpds

### Limiting retries

The danger with this is that you will perform continuous requests until the server doesn't return a 500 or 502. In a real-world app you would want to limit retries, and probably put some kind of delay in there to avoid flooding your server with requests.

To do this, you could use `take(n)` which will restrict your requests to `n` failed attempts. This won't work for you because `take` will stop the observable from proceeding to `catchError`, and you won't be able to perform navigation.

Instead, you can set a retry limit and throw an error once the retry limit has been reached.

```js
const retryLimit = 3;
let attempt = 0;

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    // retryWhen operator should come before catchError operator as it is more specific
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
      tap(error => {
        if (++attempt >= retryLimit || (error.status !== 500 && error.status !== 502)) {
          throw error;
        }
      })  
    )),

    // now catch all other errors
    catchError(error => {     
      if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 400 || error.status === 403) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('abort-access', { replaceUrl: true });
      } else if (error.status === 500 || error.status === 502) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('server-error', { replaceUrl: true });
        // do not return the error
        return empty();
      }

      return throwError("error occured");
    })
  );
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ud1t7c

Comment: Can we use retryWhen inside a subscribe method when we call an API from a component?

Comment: No. Retry when happens in the pipe before your subscribe. You can add a pipe to any observable though. `observable.pipe(map()).pipe(map()).pipe(retryWhen()).subscribe()`.

Comment: So your component would do something like `this.service.makeRequest().pipe(retryWhen()).subscribe()`

Comment: I have one doubt- if I write this.service.makeRequest().pipe(retryWhen()).subscribe((resp) => { this.list = resp }); , you mean to say this.list will not be assigned with resp untill the retry is completed?

Comment: Yes. The `retryWhen` makes another request because you received an error, so there won't be a list to work with anyway.

Comment: I tried your code, it is not going to server-error page even it failed on second time. Am I missing something?

Comment: And also it is not entering to catchError block.

Comment: Ah yes. `take` will stop the observable. Let me have a look.

Comment: Updated. Instead of `take`, you can manually track the attempts in the `tap`. I'm sure there's a nicer solution, but this should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Make this function

```
           delayedRetry(delayMs:number,maxRetry:number){

            let retries=maxRetry;

            return (src:Observable<any>)=>
            src.pipe(
           retryWhen((errors:Observable<any>)=>errors.pipe(
           delay(delayMs),
           mergeMap(error =>retries -- > 0 ? 
           of(error):throwError("Retrying..."))
     ))
   )
  
}
```

call this inside api url

```
    return this.http.get<RouteData[]>(url).pipe(
    this.delayedRetry(10000,4),
    catchError(err => {
   console.error(err);
    return EMPTY;
    }),
  shareReplay()
  );
```